# linear map question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ is a linear map if and only if there exists $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $f$ acts like multiplication by the matrix

$$\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)$$ 
Any help on this would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand the question?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{e_{1}, e_{2}\}$ be standard basis for $\Bbb{R}^{2}$, so there exists $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb{R}$ such that
$f(e_{1})=ae_{1}+ce_{2}$ and $f(e_{2})=be_{1}+de_{2}$. Now for every $(x,y)\in \Bbb{R}^{2}$ we have
$f(x,y)=xf(e_{1})+yf(e_{1})=(ax+by)e_{1}+(cx+dy)e_{2}$ (since $f$ is a linear map), now you can write f as follows:
$$f(X)=\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array} \right)X$$
for any $X\in \Bbb{R}^{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You can use following facts, commonly proved in a basic linear algebra course:

> Every linear map $h: V \to W$, where $V, W$ are vector spaces of dimensions $n$ and $m$ with bases $B$ and $D$, has a matrix $M_{m\times n}$ such that $Rep_{B,D}(h)=M_{m \times n}.$

This can be useful for only if part, and

> Any matrix represents a linear map betwen vector spaces of appropiate dimensions, with respect to any pair of bases.

can be useful for the if part.